# Get the windows system username on server from php

Tags: php

I want to get he windows system username if my file was on the server.
Because currently it is giving me my hosting server username.

I tried getenv(),$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'],get_current_user() but none of these giving me the windows system username.
When i am using the getenv() in localhost it is showing the system username, but not on the server.

Is it possible through PHP or not?

Comment: Hi, I am not at all sure what you are looking for here. What do you mean by the _windows system username_ Do you mean the userid that you logged into the server using?

Comment: yes you are right i want the windows system username.

Comment: Thats not possible. There is no reason why PHP would ever need to know that and if it did it would most likely be the beginning of a scurity issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access the PHP on the server, there are 2 users involved. The hosting server's user under which the PHP is executed on the server, and your local computer user in which your browser is running.

From your question it appears like you're trying to get the username of your local computer where you run your browser. This is not possible.

When the PHP is hosted on a server you only have access to the hosting server username.

Comment: So, it means this is not possible from php.